# Splitting a string on to several different lines in Java

Tags: java, string, console, char

I have a very long string consisting of words punctuation and spaces. I am trying to modify the string to add a new line (`\n`) after every `x` characters but while preserving whole words. For example:

> An evil human sprayed innocent students in the face with pepper spray

With `x = 20` would output like this:

```
An evil human sprayed      21 chars
innocent students in       20 chars
the face with pepper       20 chars
spray                      end of string
```

If words would be split by inserting a `\n` after `x` characters, then the word should be allowed to stay on the line, while a new line would be inserted at the end of the word.

Is there a catch-all way of doing this without a whole lot of complicated code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(.{20,}?)\\s+", "$1\n");
```

This will find every instance of at least twenty non-newline characters, followed by one or more whitespace characters, and replace the whitespace with a newline. Or, to make `x` decidable at run-time (rather than hard-coded as `20`), I'd write:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(.{" + x + ",}?)\\s+", "$1\n");
```

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was hoping for. I'm going to give a quick test run and try to break it.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Apache commons text library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/), in particular [WordUtils#wrap()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/WordUtils.html#wrap(java.lang.String,int)).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in Apache's direction. I didn't know about that package and it seems very powerful. However, for this implementation I would prefer to opt for a regex-like answer like @ruakh's (+1)