# Splitting a string after max X characters and preserve whole words

Tags: java, regex, split

I would like to split a String using regex just like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314566/splitting-a-string-on-to-several-different-lines-in-java), 
but in my case I want that each words in a new line will **not** exceed X characters.

So the following code doesn't do the trick since it finds every instance of at least X non-newline characters (and not max X).

```
s = s.replaceAll("(.{" + x + ",}?)\\s+", "$1\n");
```

**I can easily do this using other methods, but I would like to do it using a REGEX**

Comment: Have you tried: `(.{0, " + x + "})` instead?

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't work for certain scenarios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(.{0,"+ x+"})\\b", "$1\n");
```

or the trimmed version,

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?:\\s*)(.{1,"+ x +"})(?:\\s+|\\s*$)", "$1\n")
```